# Where does Chutzpah Test Adapter install PhantomJS?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, phantomjs, chutzpah

I've just installed the Chutzpah Test Adapter extension to a VS2013, and run a simple Jasmine test through VS's Test Explorer.  That worked fine - running the tests headless.

Then I tried to run the same test through Resharper's test explorer, and and that didn't work. It opened up a browser window, and then nothing happened.

I've generally preferred Resharper's test explorer, but I'm the only one on the team who's using Resharper, despite my constant nagging, which is why I'm looking at Chutzpah.  So the question, at this point, is whether I abandon the Resharper test explorer for the VS2013 test explorer, or whether I can get Resharper's to work.

Resharper Options dialog allows me to choose which browser to run the tests in, and PhantomJS is one of the options, but it needs a path to the PhantomJS executable. And here's the thing - it's my understanding that Chutzpah installs PhantomJS, but I've not been able to figure out where it put it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When installe Chutzpah as a VS extension it will drop all of its dll's and Phantom.exe in its extension install directory. This is a random folder name in C:\Users[userName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Extensions[randomFolderName]. If you go to the extensions directory you can search for phantom or try each folder.

Alternatively, you can just download phantom.exe and put it where you want it.

Comment: If the path is random, then I'd not be able to set the path in a repeatable way.  So installing PhantomJS sounds like the best choice. Thanks.